# php find two special characters next to each other.`

Tags: php, regex

I want to find two or more special characters which are next to each other.
Currently i have the following code.

```
$text = "HieTest#";
return preg_match('/[#$%^&*()+=\-\[\]\';,.\/{}|":<>?~\\\\]/', $text);
```

which check only if special character is present.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = "HieTest#";
return preg_match('/[#$%^&*()+=\-\[\]\';,.\/{}|":<>?~\\\\]{2,}/', $text);
```

Comment: No because if there is one character, it will pass

Comment: Yes indeed, my bad. +1 from me.

Comment: Because `$text = "HieTest#";` has not two (or more) special characters next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help:

```
preg_match('\W{2,}', $text);
```

`\W` match any non-word character `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Quantifier: `{2,}` Between 2 and unlimited times, as many times as possible